# Replace first n entries in a column in kdb

Tags: kdb

How can I replace the values in the first n columns of my table？

i.e. `mycol:(1 2 3 4)` to `mycol:(a a 3 4)`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If it's the values within mycol that you want updated then they will need to be of the same type as the existing values. See below.

```
q)t:([]mycol:`$string 1+til 4;mycol2:til 4)
q)update mycol:`a from t where i<2
mycol mycol2
------------
a     0
a     1
3     2
4     3
```

One way around this though is to `enlist` mycol, that way updates of any type can be made.

```
q)t:([]mycol:1+til 4;mycol2:til 4)
q)update mycol:`a from(update enlist each mycol from t)where i<2
mycol mycol2
------------
`a    0
`a    1
,3    2
,4    3
q)meta update mycol:`a from(update enlist each mycol from t)where i<2
c     | t f a
------| -----
mycol |
mycol2| j
```

It's unclear from your question whether you want the column names or the column values changed. If it's the column names, you can use `xcol`.

```
q)(2#`a)xcol([]w:3#til 3;x:3#.Q.a;y:`;z:0N)
a a y z
-------
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Comment: For follow up, I think what I am trying to do is to replace the first entries in my column with null while keeping the remaining entries the same. I am not sure how to do that

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Comment: They are float. I figured out just now tho. Thank you!!

Comment: @EmilyWilson Please don't forget to mark the answer.