# How do I replace the first 10 entries in a column with NaN in KDB

Tags: kdb

I am doing calculation on columns using summation. I want to manually change my first n entries in my calc column from float to NaN. Can someone please advise me how to do that?

For example, if my column in table t now is mycol:(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9), I am trying to get a function that can replace the first n=4 entries with NaN, so my column in table t becomes mycol:(0N 0N 0N 0N 5 6 7 8 9)

Thank you so much!

Emily

Comment: Is this not the same question you asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66810511/replace-first-n-entries-in-a-column-in-kdb

Comment: That answer is not what the problem was asking for...

Comment: Then continue the discussion in that topic to resolve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use amend functionality to replace the first n items with null value. Additionally, it would be better to use the appropriate null literal for each column based on the type. Something like this would work:

```
f: {nullDict: "ijfs"!(0Ni;0Nj;0Nf:`); @[x; til y; :; nullDict .Q.ty x]}
```

This will amend the first y items in the list x. `.Q.ty` will get the type for input so that we can get the corresponding value from the dictionary.

You can then use this for a single column, like so:

```
update mycol: f[mycol;4] from tbl
```

You can also do this in one go for multiple columns with varying number of items to be replaced using functional form:

```
![tbl;();0b;`mycol`mycol2!((f[;4];`mycol);(f[;3];`mycol2))]
```

Do take note that you will need to modify `nullDict` with whatever other types you need.

Update: Thanks to Jonathon McMurray for suggesting a better way to build up `nullDict` for all primitive types using the below code:

```
{x!first each x$\:()}.Q.t except " "
```

Comment: rather than manually building the `nullDict`, you could use `{x!first each x$\:()}.Q.t except " "` to get appropriate nulls for all primitive data types

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea. Mind if I add it in?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can I ask what if my table is rolling. i.e, I want to replace first 15 entries in a column with NaN, but it may be the case that I do not have 14 rows yet. Is there a way to add that condition in?

Comment: @shree.pat18 go ahead :)